# Arrange items in a column. Each column contains the same value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame and I want to arrange the symbols in the columns from (0-15) so that each column contains the same symbol, for example, column (0) contains ZY705, column (1) contains ZY405, and so on.

```
Semester number        Semester AVREGE  0        1        2        3        4
  1               14        S   FAIL  'ZY405'  'ZY504'  'ZY510'  'ZY601'  'ZY605'
2                 15        F   FAIL  'ZY504'  'ZY601'  'ZY603'     None     None
3                 16        S   FAIL  'ZY504'  'ZY704'  'ZY705'     None     None
4                 17        F   FAIL  'ZY704'     None     None     None     None
```

I want to organize the equal row values under the same columns:

```
Semester number        Semester AVREGE  0        1        2        3        4
  1               14        S   FAIL  'ZY405'  'ZY504'  'ZY510'  'NAN'  'ZY605'
2                 15        F   FAIL  'NAN'     'ZY504'  'NAN'     ZY705     NAN
3                 16        S   FAIL  'ZY405'     NAN    'ZY510'     NAN     NAN
4                 17        F   FAIL  'ZY405'      NAN     NAN       NAN     NAN
```

Comment: Why column 0 should contain ZY705? and column1 ZY405?

Comment: I want to arrange the symbols so that each symbol is in a column to apply an Aprori algorithm

Comment: For your input dataframe, can you update your post with the expect outcome, please?

Comment: Can you include how the output would look like for the given input in the question?

Comment: Each column contains only one symbol, and the number of columns depends on the number of symbols